# Extract multiple objects with the same name from a library

Tags: static-libraries, bsd, unix-ar, .a

I have a `.a` file that contains a number of objects that share the same name (`utils.o` for example).
How can I extract these objects when the `ar` utility only operates on the name?

Answer (score 3):

`man ar` reveals this modifier:

```
   N   Uses  the  count  parameter.  This is used if there are multiple entries in the archive with the same name.
       Extract or delete instance count of the given name from the archive.
```

So, for example, you could use `ar xN 5 libfoo.a utils.o` to extract the 5th `utils.o` object from your archive...

Comment: Is GNU only. The BSD version (on OSX for example) doesn't have that.